# Change Line Highlight Position in PhpStorm

Tags: editor, phpstorm

A weird issue: in PhpStorm when I use the default font the line highlighting looks fine.

[image: Correct highlighting]

But when I change the font to Consolas (my preferred font) the highlighting is not vertically centered correctly.

[image: Incorrect highlighting]

I'm a newbie in PhpStorm and can't find any setting to adjust this. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no setting for this but the issue should be fixed in latest IDE versions: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-67480
Are you using 2017.1.4?

Comment: I apologise - I was using 2016.3.3 and didn't think to update. The latest version is working correctly.